# Is it possible to use the iOS/Android development tools shipped with Visual Studio 2015 to compile Qt?

Tags: android, ios, qt5, visual-studio-2015

We are starting a new project - an application that will be deployed on iOS and Android (and Windows Phone later on) and we want to build it on top of Qt. It would be nice to be able to support all of these in a single development environment - Visual Studio to be more exact. If Android is not an issue here since we can build Qt with the Android NDK then at least so far iOS was a show stopper.

Visual Studio 2015 has added mobile development tools for Android and iOS. So what I would like to hear from someone already using these tools is how reliable/usable they actually are and in a perfect scenario if anyone has tried to build Qt for iOS with these tools? Currently I have no idea what these tools consist of - a fully working compiler or something else.

I checked the Qt bug tracker for any possible feature requests on this but did not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official Qt Visual Studio Add-In (https://wiki.qt.io/Visual_Studio_Add-in, https://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/07/03/visual-studio-add-in-1-2-2-released/) but it seems like it is not being developed anymore.

You can also use Qt Creator, which also supports iOS and Android development ontop of Qt, but for native code you should still consider to use XCode or Android Studio.

For both IDEs you still need XCode to build iOS Apps, so you can't completely avoid using multiple IDEs.

Comment: I am well aware that I can use Qt Creator and the Add-In, what I am interested in is building Qt for iOS using the MSVC 2015 iOS development tools.

Comment: @Steffen that addin wont work on 2015 `These instructions refer to Visual Studio 2012. Replace any references to VS2012 with the appropriate file for your VS version (2008, 2010 and 2012 supported).`